# What is the impact of await and .then() on the stack?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

I'm having trouble understanding the control flow in the following code. The `await` in the `await setTimeout(() => console.log("Await timeout executed"), 0)` line seems to yield control back to the main thread, causing `'I am in main()'` to be logged to the console. If I remove the `await`, the order of the output changes -- "The function is done executing" now comes before "I am in the main thread".  I understand the rest of the code but don't get what the stack looks like here. Do `await` and `.then()` always return control to the caller? If so, how does the program know to put those functions back on the stack? Thanks.

```js
async function test () {
  console.log("Execution starting");

  setTimeout(() => console.log("Timeout executed"), 0);

  await setTimeout(() => console.log("Await timeout executed"), 0);

  Promise.resolve(5).then(function log() { console.log("Hello from the first promise!") })

  console.log('The function is done executing')
}

test()
console.log('I am in main()')

//Execution starting
//I am in main()
//The function is done executing
//Hello from the first promise!
//Timeout executed
//Await timeout executed
```